# Bernoulli vs. binomial process

Tags: stochastic-processes, binomial-distribution

Can the difference between **Binomial process** and **Bernoulli process with the parameter $p$** be
explained ?

Comment: A Binomial RV is the sum of $n$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli RVs

Comment: I am not familiar with a "binomial process." However, a Bernoulli process with parameter $p$ is a sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ of independent $\mathsf{Ber}$(p)-distributed random variables. The connection between the Bernoulli process and the Binomial distribution is that for any $n,k>0$ and $Y\sim\mathsf{Bin}(n,p)$ we have $$Y\stackrel d=\sum_{j=k}^{k+n-1} X_j.$$

Comment: @Math1000 What do you think is the distinction/connection between a **process** and a **distribution** ? And what role plays the variable $k$ in your formula ?

Comment: $k$ is not a variable, it is a fixed index. For example, if $Y\sim\mathsf{Bin}(n,p)$ and $k=3$ then $Y\stackrel d=\sum_{j=3}^{3+n-1} X_j$.

Comment: I do see on Wikipedia the notion of a **Binomial process** but this is not something with which I am acquainted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_process

Comment: @user122424 a *stochastic process* is a family of *random variables* typically indexed over time. A Bernoulli process for instance, can be given as a sequence of IIDRVs $(B_n)_{n\geq 1}$ where each $B_n\sim B(p)$ for some $0<p<1$ (here time is taken as discrete moments $n=1,2,\dotsc$). The *distribution*, specifically the *cumulative distribution function* is given by $\mathbb{P}(B_n \leq j)$. Completely different objects technically speaking but each random variable has a distribution associated to it so sometimes the terminology gets abused.